# Finiteness and summability of Fourier transform

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

> Let $f$ be 1-periodic, $m$ times continuously differentiable function on
> $\mathbb{R}$
>
> 1- Show that: $$ \sup_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} |n|^m |\hat{f}(n)| < \infty$$
> where $\hat{f}(n)$ is the Fourier transform of $f$.
>
> 2- Show that
>
> $$\sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} |\hat{f}(n)|< \infty$$

Could someone please suggest how to approach proving these statements?

Answer (score 1):

Say, $m=1$, integration by parts gives
\begin{align*}
\widehat{f}(n)=\int_{\mathbb{T}}f(x)e^{-2\pi inx}dx=\dfrac{1}{2\pi in}\int_{\mathbb{T}}f'(x)e^{-2\pi inx}dx,
\end{align*}
so $|n\widehat{f}(n)|\leq\|f'\|_{L^{\infty}(\mathbb{T})}$.

For higher $m$, perform several times integration by parts trick.

If $m\geq 2$, then
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n}|\widehat{f}(n)|\leq\left(\sup_{n}|n|^{m}|\widehat{f}(n)|\right)\cdot\sum_{n}\dfrac{1}{|n|^{m}}<\infty.
\end{align*}

If $m=1$, then
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n}|\widehat{f}(n)|=\dfrac{1}{2\pi}\sum_{n}\dfrac{1}{|n|}\cdot|\widehat{f'}(n)|\leq\dfrac{1}{2\pi}\left(\sum_{n}\dfrac{1}{|n|^{2}}\right)^{1/2}\left(\sum_{n}|\widehat{f'}(n)|^{2}\right)^{1/2}.
\end{align*}
But
\begin{align*}
\left(\sum_{n}|\widehat{f'}(n)|^{2}\right)^{1/2}=\|f'\|_{L^{2}(\mathbb{T})}<\infty.
\end{align*}